# When should I use new class instead of adding new field (as state)?

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns

I saw some design pattern book and I noticed some interesting point: They creates a lot of classes. Some times it seems that I can add one field instead of creating class. For example

Implementation using class:

```
public class Animal
{

}


public class Dog : Animal
{

}
```

Implementation using state:

```
public class Animal
{
    public AnimalType AnimalType;
}

var dog = new Animal();
dog.AnimalType = AnimalType.Dog;
```

Maybe there is another better way to create dog object, I just tried to make point. So which approach is better?

Comment: This seems like it'd be a better fit for [Programmers SE](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What you're asking us to answer is the entire composition vs inheritance debate. This is very broad and you'll be better off reading a book (or some indepth articles) on OO design. Here I would use inheritance because a dog can't suddenly become a cat so there is no benefit using composition (it would just make it hard to use).

Comment: @user3580294 how i can move the question there?

Comment: This is precisely why I find the "positively discriminatory" expression "Favor composition over inheritance" so distasteful.

Comment: I *think* the way to go about it is to flag the question for mod attention and state that you wish it be moved to Programmers SE, but I'm not 100% sure about it...

Answer (score 2):

You create different classes to have different behavior like:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void makeASound();
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    public void makeASound() {
        System.out.println("bark, bark!");
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal {
    public void makeASound() {
        System.out.println("mrau, mrau");
    }
}
```

They both inherit the `Animal` class so you can ask for an animal to do something with it, but you don't care which implementation you get.

With a type field you would have to do different behaviour in conditional statements

```
if(animalType == AnimalType.Dog){
    System.out.println("bark, bark!");
} else if(animalType == AnimalType.Cat){
    System.out.println("mrau, mrau!");
}
```

That would become very hard to maintain.

Why to have `Animal`, `Dog`, `Cat` and other animals, instead of just `Dog`, `Cat`,  other animals?

Inheritance allows you to ask for a class which can do something, but you don't care how exactly this class does it. You may want to encrypt some data, so you write a method which as an argument takes `EncryptionAlgorithm` class and uses it. But the application's user can choose different algorithms, so you write different classes like `Rijndael`, `DES`, `Serpent`, `Twofish` which all inherits `EncryptionAlgorithm` class, and all of them can by passed as an argument to a method which takes `EncryptionAlgorithm`. So you don't have to create 4 methods like

```
encryptUsingRijndael(Rijndael algorithm)
encryptUsingTwofish(Twofish algorithm)
encryptUsingDES(DES algorithm)
encryptUsingSerpent(Serpent algorithm)
```

Which all do the same thing, but to different class. You write only one method's

```
encrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm algorithm)
```

And you can pass whichever algorithm the application's user wants to use.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a subclass allows you to define custom implementations of methods. If you use one or more "attribute" fields in a single class, it forces you to deal with the logic of every possible permutation of attribute values in a single location. By using subclasses, you have a logical grouping of functionality instead of just another combination of attributes.

On a side note, using a field to describe a class does not necessarily mean it's stateful. If the field is immutable (e.g. declaring a primitive with the `final` keyword) you would still be avoiding inheritance without a "state".